# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (File is created but contains nothing)

Tags: c#, file-io, exception, append, .net

```
using System.IO;

class test
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string path=@"c:\mytext.txt";

        if(File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }


        FileStream fs=new FileStream(path,FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamWriter str=new StreamWriter(fs);
        str.BaseStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.End); 
        str.Write("mytext.txt.........................");
        str.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()+" "+DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        string addtext="this line is added"+Environment.NewLine;
        File.AppendAllText(path,addtext);  //Exception occurrs ??????????
        string readtext=File.ReadAllText(path);
        Console.WriteLine(readtext);
        str.Flush();
        str.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();
  //System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\mytext.txt' because it is //being used by another process.
  // at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try This

```
string path = @"c:\mytext.txt";

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}

{ // Consider File Operation 1
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(fs);
    str.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    str.Write("mytext.txt.........................");
    str.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " " + 
                  DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
    string addtext = "this line is added" + Environment.NewLine;
    str.Flush();
    str.Close();
    fs.Close();
    // Close the Stream then Individually you can access the file.
}

File.AppendAllText(path, addtext);  // File Operation 2

string readtext = File.ReadAllText(path); // File Operation 3

Console.WriteLine(readtext);
```

In every File Operation, The File will be Opened and must be Closed prior Opened. Like wise in the Operation 1 you must Close the File Stream for the Further Operations.

Answer (score 5):

You are writing to the file prior to closing your filestream:

```
using(FileStream fs=new FileStream(path,FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
using (StreamWriter str=new StreamWriter(fs))
{
   str.BaseStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.End); 
   str.Write("mytext.txt.........................");
   str.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()+" "+DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
   string addtext="this line is added"+Environment.NewLine;

   str.Flush();

}

File.AppendAllText(path,addtext);  //Exception occurrs ??????????
string readtext=File.ReadAllText(path);
Console.WriteLine(readtext);
```

The above code should work, using the methods you are currently using.  You should also look into the `using` statement and wrap your streams in a using block.

Answer (score 2):

`File.AppendAllText` does not know about the stream you have opened, so will internally try to open the file again. Because your stream is blocking access to the file, `File.AppendAllText` will fail, throwing the exception you see.

I suggest you used `str.Write` or `str.WriteLine` instead, as you already do elsewhere in your code.

Your file is created but contains nothing because the exception is thrown before `str.Flush()` and `str.Close()` are called.

Answer (score -2):

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    sw.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Comment: You should try and add some more information to this answer. Why does your code fix the original issue?